# US visa in a damaged passport

Tags: usa, passports

I am a returning student to the US. My passport suffered water damage but the personal details and US visa page is legible. I have applied for a new passport .

My question is: Can I travel to the US with the new passport and the original with the valid US visa?

Comment: That is for sure a duplicate. Yes, that is never an issue. Bring the old passport with you and you are fine.